# Repeating each elements of an Eigen Matrix both row wise and column wise

Tags: eigen

Given an Eigen Matrix, say

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> A(2, 2);
A << 11, 12, 21, 22;
```

what is the most elegant way to obtain a matrix B of dimensions 4x4 from A, where each element of A is repeated once both row wise and column wise.

```
11 11 12 12
11 11 12 12
21 21 22 22
21 21 22 22
```

I am looking for a generic solution that could scale to any given row and column sizes of A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the head of Eigen you write such a `repelem` in a few lines of code:

```
template<typename XprType, typename RowFactorType, typename ColFactorType>
auto repelem(const XprType &xpr, RowFactorType row_factor, ColFactorType col_factor) {
    using namespace Eigen;

    const int RowFactor = internal::get_fixed_value<RowFactorType>::value;
    const int ColFactor = internal::get_fixed_value<ColFactorType>::value;
    const int NRows = XprType::RowsAtCompileTime == Dynamic || RowFactor == Dynamic ? Dynamic : XprType::RowsAtCompileTime*RowFactor;
    const int NCols = XprType::ColsAtCompileTime == Dynamic || ColFactor == Dynamic ? Dynamic : XprType::ColsAtCompileTime*ColFactor;
    const int nrows = internal::get_runtime_value(row_factor) * xpr.rows();
    const int ncols = internal::get_runtime_value(col_factor) * xpr.cols();

    return xpr(
        Array<int,NRows,1>::LinSpaced(nrows,0,xpr.rows()-1),
        Array<int,NCols,1>::LinSpaced(ncols,0,xpr.cols()-1)
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
Array22i A;
A << 1, 2, 3, 4;
std::cout << repelem(A,2,2) << "\n";
```

Full demo: https://godbolt.org/z/rYgDxF

This code might look a bit complicated but it is so to preserve compile-time sizes as proved by the following test:

```
Array22i A;
static_assert(decltype(repelem(A,fix<2>,fix<2>))::RowsAtCompileTime==4,"Bad compile-time size");
```

People can track its inclusion within Eigen [there](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=1778).

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic. Works perfectly.